# How to hide/delete individual holidays on Google Calendar?

Tags: google-calendar

I enabled US holidays on my Google Calendar. However, there are individual "holidays" that I do not want to show up on my calendar since they are irrelevant to me and I don't want them to conceal the other events I've scheduled for that day. Is there a way to hide/delete individual holidays from Google Calendar (without removing the holiday calendar altogether)?

Answer (score 5):

The same as Peter's answer above. The quick way to remove non-holidays for Google Calendar is within settings through a browser (not on mobile app). Hover over the "Holidays in the US" calendar and click the three dots, then Settings. About midway down is a drop-box for Holiday Calendar Content. Select "Public holidays only".

Unfortunately this also drops Fathers and Mothers day and the other more respected non-holidays, so those would have to be added manually or with another shared calendar.

A good workaround is the US Holidays from Calendarlabs.com. Download the ical and import as a new calendar (that way you can control it). It's pretty clean as is, but I deleted the public holidays (Memorial, Labor...) from this import, left the google one turned on, and now I have a decent set of both true public holidays, and widely accepted non-holidays.

I also fully agree with Peter. Not all these "months" and days are widely accepted. Google needs to separate them and let us choose which groups to add. They have sports, moon phases, global religious, why not separate Fathers/Mothers, black, homo-sexual, etc then let us choose?

Answer (score 4):

There is not a way to delete specific holidays Google lists.  You can only choose "Google" holidays or federal holidays.  If you choose Googles list you get Father's Day and LGBTQ Month listed.  No way to get Father's Day and not LGBTQ month listing for example.

Answer (score 4):

In your calendar settings change:

- Settings for other calendars
- Holidays in United States
- Calendar settings

Set Holiday calendar content
to "Public holidays only" instead of "Public holidays and other holidays".

Comment: Anyone know how to do this for "Holidays in United Kingdom" (to hide Valentine's Day, Shrove Tuesday etc).

I can't see a "Holiday Calendar Content" option, yet the popup says you should be able to hide observances within settings

Answer (score 0):

The answer posted by @Peter Jensen was exactly what I was looking for and why I needed a solution. My calendar appointments are hidden because of events I don't care about and don't need on my calendar. Thanks Peter!

[How to hide/delete individual holidays on Google Calendar?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/150228/how-to-hide-delete-individual-holidays-on-google-calendar/154821#154821)

Regarding the removed holidays of use (e.g. Halloween, Mothers/Fathers day, etc) you can create a new calendar and manually add them back. I added the keyword custom but retained the original calendar name and coloration to make them indistinguishable from each other.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there is a way to customize.  You can delete the entire US Holiday calendar and enter the holidays you choose.